# Restringir acesso por htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, servidor

Tenho um servidor dedicado separado da hospedagem do meu site, alguns conteúdos como imagem, vídeos, textos e etc serão puxados desse dedicado, o problema é que eu gostaria de restringir o acesso a esses arquivos diretamente pela URL, e deixar eles acessiveis somente se a solicitação vier diretamente do site, já tentei usar o Allow from IP, porém o ip que vai é o IP do usuário e não o do meu site, o que poderia ser um problema no futuro... já tentei usar o HTTP REFERER porém não funcionou, alguém pode me dizer o que posso fazer para limitar e exibir esse conteúdo somente dentro do site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondendo a pergunta, antes de mais nada, o bloqueio para requisições de fora via `.htaccess` é algo assim:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.seusite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://seusite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
```

Mas isto é só para dificultar um pouco para os curiosos, pois qualquer coisa que o navegador acessa sem restrição, pode ser acessado diretamente por uma requisição externa. Os cabeçalhos HTTP são facilmente simulados.

Para proteger contra acessos automatizados, um captcha ajudaria, mas isso é inviável para recursos normais, como imagens, JS, CSS, áudio etc que seriam usados normalmente pelo site. Além disso, nada impediria do usuário responder o captcha numa aplicação externa ao site.

É praticamente impossível um bloqueio razoável sem efeitos colaterais no contexto apresentado na pergunta.

A vantagem do bloqueio por REFERER é no caso de *Hot Link*, ele ao menos evita que seus recursos sejam linkados em sites de terceiros (porque neste caso, o terceiro não tem controle sobre o navegador do usuário, que estará fazendo a requisição). Você não tem como impedir que este terceiro acesse seus dados e tire uma cópia, mas ele mesmo não tem como fazer com que os usuários comuns (do site dele) contornem a sua proteção de maneira simples e acessem seus arquivos diretamente. Ao menos desincentiva o consumo indevido da banda de transmissão do seu servidor, pois neste caso ele é obrigado a ao menos intermediar o conteúdo.

Não posso negar nem confirmar que já fiz isso `:P`, mas controlando o REFERER diretamente na sua apliação, você poderia muito bem servir uma imagem extremamente inadequada se for linkada num site de terceiros, mas correta se a pessoa acessar pelo seu site ou se o REFERER estiver vazio (importante considerar que só é *hotlink* se vier preenchido, e com site errado). **Não recomendo**, pois pode ficar no cache da pessoa, e aparecer coisa errada se futuramente a mesma pessoa acessar seu site diretamente, dando um resultado desastroso. Mas sempre é bom saber que é possível ;)

Comment: Entendi, já estava pensando sobre isso mesmo, tenho uma função que verifica a existência de arquivos nesse servidor, porém o mesmo diz que os arquivos não existem, sendo que se eu acessar o mesmo arquivo direto pela URL ele existe, poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Me parece ser um problema diferente (seria o caso de abrir pergunta separada). Lembre-se de postar o código na nova pergunta. Lembre-se de dar uma pesquisada antes se não tem alguma similar já.

Comment: Ok obrigado, voltando a minha pergunta atual, então não existe nenhum método de bloquear requisições de arquivos no meu servidor dedicado, através do Firewall ou do próprio Apache? É que eu realmente gostaria de deixar esses arquivos visíveis só no site

Comment: Impossível. Tudo que o navegador faz, pode ser feito diretamente pelo cliente (que é basicamente o que eu já respondi acima).

Comment: Entendo, vou usar então o RewriteCond pra dificultar um pouco, já é um começo.

Comment: Não seria possível também colocar uma senha na pasta com esses arquivos e na hora de solicitar eles no site, mandas as informações de acesso junto com o embed?

Comment: E o que impede da pessoa linkar com as mesmas informações? Se ela copia o URL, pode copiar as credenciais. Minha sugestão é fazer algo que não dependa deste tipo de bloqueio. Você vai ficar perdendo horas para bolar algo que um atacante vai quebrar em minutos (seja lá que solução encontrar).

Comment: Elas não poderiam ser passadas de alguma forma oculta? Um post, algo do tipo? Ou posso criar um scripts para receber a requisição e então dizer de onde a mesma está vindo e preparar o arquivo para envio?

Comment: Hoje em dia sites como os Correios, Registro.br, Secretaria da fazenda, etc não consegem bloquear isso. Como eu já disse, não tem como. Só com artifícios como captcha e coisas do tipo, mas isso inviabiliza uso no próprio site. Não adiantaria eu listar todas as formas de contorno na resposta, mas tenha a clareza de que não tem solução que não comprometa o uso normal. Pode fazer o que for, vai sempre ter contorno. No máximo, cria dificuldades, mas sempre vai perder muito mais tempo do que quem for contornar. O mais "Barato" é o REFERER, quem passa ele passa o resto.

Comment: Entendi, vou trabalhar melhor na ocultação da URL do arquivo numa versão futura então ultilizando BLOB, de qualquer forma obrigado por sua ajuda <3 vou abrir outra questão para a verificação dos arquivos